# what kind of energy is emited from black holes

Tags: black-holes

Is it possible that the mass/energy that is absorbed by black holes could be converted to space time and causing the universe to expand?

Comment: According to GR, the expansion of the universe doesn't require the existence of black holes (a simple expanding universe model assumes a uniform distribution of mass-energy).  Why do you wish to invoke black holes as a cause for the expansion of the universe?

Comment: Black holes are regions where time is slowed down arbitrary close to stopping. Everything that falls there remains outside, but it's mass/energy is reduced arbitrary close to zero and converted to the energy of the gravitational field (curved spacetime) outside the black hole. Any type of energy can be emitted from outside. The curvature of spacetime around the black hole does not mean "more" spacetime, so this has nothing to do with the expansion of the universe. Hypothetically, the universe inside a black hole is quickly contracting at 64% the speed of light until time stops at the center.

Answer (score 1):

> What kind of energy is emitted by Black holes ?

The only form of energy we *think* is emitted directly from a black hole (and not from the material around a black hole) is [Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation).  This has not been observed and quite possibly is never going to be observed as the effect under normal circumstances is extremely small.

> Is it possible that the mass/energy that is absorbed by black holes could be converted to space time and causing the universe to expand ?

Spacetime is not any form of "converted energy" as far as we know.  Certainly things that are forms of energy exist in spacetime and certainly they can distort spacetime, but spacetime itself is not a form of energy (at least in any sense we know).

The expansion of the universe is (more or less) explained by a "basic" piece of cosmology theory called the [FLRW metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric) (named for the initials of the people who developed it).

It turns out that modern interpretations of this means that we have a mystery called [Dark Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy) associated with the expansion of the universe.  One way of looking at this is that the universe seems to generate a kind of background energy to fill in spacetime as it expands.  No one knows what dark energy is and it's best to think of it as place holder until we figure that out (or find a theory that doesn't need it).

Comment: +1 If anything, the increased mass of the black hole from material falling into it should act to make the universe *contract*, rather than expand.